# In R data.table, how can we use a variable in brackets as a container of column index numbers?

Tags: r, data.table

In my project

```
dftask2[, 56 ]

dftask2[, cols[1] ]
```

codes return different values while cols[1] = 56 actually. First line returns whole column while the second one returns 56 value. What is the reason of this? Can we use a variable as a holder of different indices?

Comment: You can use `dftask2[, cols[1], with = FALSE]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to "use a variable as a holder of different indices", then you have (at least) two options

1. Specity `with` argument as `FALSE`:

```r
dftask2[, cols[1], with = F]
```

2. try with `get`:

```r
dftask2[, get('cols')[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `.SDcols`

```
dftask2[, .SD, .SDcols = cols[1]]
```

Comment: Why is ".SD" used here?

Comment: @EmreKara It is the Subset of Data.table